# FastAPI Raises Missing Positional Argument Error

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi, python-3.9

The following code raises the following exception.

I'm not sure I fully understand how FastAPI works. Could someone help me understand?

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi import BackgroundTasks
from fastapi import Request

app = FastAPI()

async def parse_request(req: Request):
    print(req)
    print(req.client.host)

@app.route("/endpoint")
async def endpoint(request: Request, background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    background_tasks.add_task(parse_request, request)
    return {"msg": "ok"}
```

Exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/repos/fastapi_pg/env_39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/h11_impl.py", line 396, in run_asgi
    result = await app(self.scope, self.receive, self.send)
  File "/home/user/repos/fastapi_pg/env_39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 45, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/user/repos/fastapi_pg/env_39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 199, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/user/repos/fastapi_pg/env_39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 112, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/user/repos/fastapi_pg/env_39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 181, in __call__
    raise exc from None
  File "/home/user/repos/fastapi_pg/env_39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 159, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/home/user/repos/fastapi_pg/env_39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 82, in __call__
    raise exc from None
  File "/home/user/repos/fastapi_pg/env_39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 71, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/home/user/repos/fastapi_pg/env_39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 580, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/user/repos/fastapi_pg/env_39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 241, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/user/repos/fastapi_pg/env_39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 52, in app
    response = await func(request)
TypeError: endpoint() missing 1 required positional argument: 'background_tasks'
```

I've gotten this to work without the `Request` param when I pass in my own variable in the route path:

```
@app.get("/test/{input_str}")
async def test(input_str: str, background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    background_tasks.add_task(do_stuff, input_str)
    return {"Hello": "World"}
```

Seems like Starlette doesn't know how to handle multiple of these params being passed so you can't mix and match. Ideal I'd be able to take the `Request` and `Header` objects and pass them to a background task for processing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The decorator `@app.route` seems to be the problem. (see: https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/912) Use `@app.api_route` instead or even better `@app.get` or `@app.post`.

Comment: Dang! Silly that this is it, but it is!